# Ajax Pagination Wicket. Retrieve new data from db when next page is clicked

Tags: ajax, pagination, navigation, wicket-6

I want to paginate my results. First I've tried the classic way and it worked, my dataView retrieves a list with results from database and displays the number of results I want per page. 
(Looks like this << <1 2 3 4 5> >> )

```
final DataView<RequestEntity> dataView = new MyDataView();
dataView.setItemsPerPage(10);

linksContainer.add(new PagingNavigator("pageNavigator", dataView));

<a wicket:id="pageNavigator"></a>
```

Now I want to retrieve data from database only when the next page is clicked (kind of lazy loading/ lazy pagination). So I modified my DAOObject like this:
    query.setMaxResults(entriesPerPage);

It is the same query like before but this time it will take the amount of results I want per page.
And it works, it retrieves as much entries as I want per page. The problem is that I don't know how to display another page. It appears just one page with the first entries from the query. (Looks like this << 1 >>)

My idea is to use links instead of AjaxPagingNavigator to display pages from 1 to 5 and when the link is clicked the query is executed. I don't think my idea is good. Can you help me? I hope my question isn't too stupid. 
Thanks

Comment: Possibly similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987036/pagelistview-and-dataset-loading   Another one is https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/wicket_jpa_glassfish_and_java

Comment: I have already queried for count to find out the number of elements my list will have. The problem is that I don't know how to display all pages from begining because the number of displayed pages depends on the list size. And I tried to add null objects in the list to trick it to show me more pages and it works but when I want to go to next page it shows the null elements. I need to query again for next results when next page is clicked.But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! All I needed to do is to create IDataProvider that knows everything. If you create it you don't need to worry about the size( about tricking it to show more pages).

```
IDataProvider dataProvider = new IDataProvider<RequestEntity>() {
    RequestEntityDAOExtra requestEntityDAOExtra =
            ((MyApp) getApplication()).getMyRequestDAO();
    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends RequestEntity> iterator(long first, long count) {
        List<RequestEntity> entitiesByDomainList = requestEntityDAOExtra.getEntityByDomain(
                domainInput.getModelObject(), (int) count, (int) first);
        return entitiesByDomainList.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return requestEntityDAOExtra.getEntityByDomainCount(domainInput.getModelObject());
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<RequestEntity> model(final RequestEntity requestEntity) {
        return new LoadableDetachableModel() {
            @Override
            protected RequestEntity load() {
                return requestEntity;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {

    }
};


final DataView<RequestEntity> dataView = new MyDataView(dataProvider, 10);

private class MyDataView extends DataView<RequestEntity> {
    public MyDataView(IDataProvider dataProvider, int i) {
        super("linksList", dataProvider, i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final Item<RequestEntity> item) {
        .....
    }
}
```